# how to compare integer properties in filter mediation in wso2 esb?

Tags: filter, wso2, esb, mediator

i am new in wso2 esb and define 3 service that return integer value and use filter mediator to rout from one to another , but not correct work and in filter mode always return false
my source is :

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="SeqOne">
<log level="full"/>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:m0="http://tempuri.org/"        name="CParam" expression="//m0:SumSerViseResponse/m0:SumSerViseResult" scope="default"   type="INTEGER"/>
<log level="custom">
  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="CParam"  expression="$ctx:CParam"/>
</log>
<property name="propertyA" value="4" scope="default" type="INTEGER"/>
<log level="custom">
  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="propertyA" expression="get-property('propertyA')"/>
</log>
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="propertyCompare" expression="$ctx:CParam > get-property('propertyA')" type="STRING"/>
<log level="custom">
  <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="propertyCompare" expression="get-property('propertyCompare')"/>
</log>
<filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" source="get-property('propertyCompare')" regex="true">
  <then>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried your scenario and got the same output as yours. Then looked deep into it as this was a basic functionality and as I thought I've done something similar before.

The issue here is in the type of the property. For some strange reason `INTEGER` does not work here. You need to have `DOUBLE` or `STRING`. Even if you have string, it will correctly cast it when you do a comparison as in here. The following worked for me.

```
<inSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <property xmlns:m0="http://tempuri.org/"
               name="CParam"
               expression="//m0:SumSerViseResponse/m0:SumSerViseResult"
               scope="default"
               type="DOUBLE"/>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="CParam" expression="$ctx:CParam"/>
     </log>
     <property name="propertyA" value="4.0" scope="default" type="DOUBLE"/>
     <log level="custom">
        <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                  name="propertyA"
                  expression="get-property('propertyA')"/>
     </log>
     <property name="propertyCompare"
               expression="$ctx:CParam > get-property('propertyA')"
               scope="default"
               type="BOOLEAN"/>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="propertyCompare" expression="get-property('propertyCompare')"/>
     </log>
     <filter xpath="$ctx:CParam > get-property('propertyA')">
        <then>
           <send>
              <endpoint>
                 <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
              </endpoint>
           </send>
        </then>
        <else>
           <drop/>
        </else>
     </filter>
  </inSequence>
```

Answer (score 1):

following is an example done with switch mediator,

```
<switch source="get-property('propertyCompare')">
        <case regex="1">
           <log>
              <property name="one" value="__________ONE__________"/>
           </log>
        </case>
        <case regex="2">
           <log>
              <property name="two" value="__________TWO__________"/>
           </log>
        </case>
     </switch>
```

replace the log mediators with send mediator according to your needs.

Comment: this error occur before receive in filter. in propertycompare